# Rubble. A fabricated operator?

Tags: education

I have previously heard about the mathematics operation Rubble. I think it's fabricated, and I want to get this confirmed.

Rubble have the symbol $h$, but backwards. It works as addition, times two.

Examples:

$1h1\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 4$

$50h50\Rightarrow 100\Rightarrow 200$

Comment: I've never heard of this, but of course there is no reason you couldn't define a binary operation on the reals (say) by $(x,y)\mapsto 2(x+y)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Rubble

Comment: I couldn't find the source of this particular operation, but many math competitions have problems where they introduce a new operation and symbol just for that problem. For instance, I recall $x\heartsuit y$ being used to denote $|x-y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete shot in the dark, but the Hamburglar was a character in oldish McDonald's commercials. He said "rubble rubble" a lot. Kind of sounds like "double double."

And the operator is an $h$.

Maybe the term was the fabrication of a fairly cool math professor who ate a lot of Happy Meals?

Comment: Thanks for improving our Culture with a big C/big mac...